# Error Code 0xc0000018 when trying to direct dial in Skype

Tags: windows-8.1, skype

I am trying to use Skype on my Dell Inspiron 15, 3000 series laptop to click to call directly from websites, but keep getting a windows error message:

> Skypelcon.exe Application Error - the application was unable to start correctly (0xc000018). Click OK to close the application.

I only get this error when trying to use Skype to direct dial.  I have no problems if I type in the phone number and dial directly, and I don't get the error with any other software that I have installed. (No games) I am currently running 8.1.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Skype yet?

Comment: http://www.ghacks.net/2015/10/16/fixing-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc0000018-in-windows/

Comment: several times.  Both Skype and the direct dialer.

Answer (score 0):

To discover what is causing this issue, first use Procmon (From Sysinternals) and start skype (ignore all others processes). Then check to see what is the last .dll that was called and then try to uninstall if you can this dll. 
This fix works also with all other cases of 0xc0000018 errors.

Comment: Uninstalling arbitrary DLLs is extraordinarily inadvisable, as doing so will almost certainly break applications that depend on them.

Comment: Yes, in this case I'm uninstalling a dll that is breaking my navigation. So is more advise to do it instead of stay without navigation. Also the next implicit step is look for an update for this app that provides those dll.